# How to calibrate a shunt with a MM and another shunt

Tags: current, measurement, shunt

I had noticed someone in my lab calibrated a shunt with a MM and another shunt, was wondering how they went about this?

Thank You

Comment: By comparing results of measure ... for some kind only.

Comment: Why can't you ask the person in the lab? How much of an EE expert was that person?

Comment: Probably by providing a constant current (like 1A) and measuring the voltage drop across the shunts in millivolts (mV).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I would have asked the senior lab person except that its the type of situation where have to walk on egg shells around this individual, very close minded.

Comment: Don't forget "Kelvin wiring" if needed. ...

Answer (score 0):

Without asking the lab guys, this is how I have done it.

Assume that the lab has a reference shunt of \$10m\Omega\$, \$R_1\$ in Figure 1. Assume that the uncertain shunt is supposed to be \$20m\Omega\$ but is closer to \$21m\Omega\$ shown as \$R_2\$ in Figure 1. The shunts are placed in series with a current. The actual value of the current is not important within limit. Connecting the shunts in series ensures that the current through each shunt is equal.

1. Measure the voltage across the reference shunt (Figure 1).
2. Measure the voltage across the the uncertain shunt (Figure 2). \$R_2\$ should be twice \$R_1\$, therefore \$V_{R_2}\$ should be twice \$V_{R_1}\$.
3. Adjust the uncertain shunt until \$V_{R_2}=2V_{R_1}\$. Figure 3.

For high resistance shunts and high precision, meter loading must be taken into account.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJQjCE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nice, got it ...............thank you